# Roblox Studio how do i change only the Y value of a part's CFrame

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to only change the player's torso's CFrame to add 1 to the Y value every second for 10 seconds.

Comment: Could you please edit the question and provide some code. Show us what you've already tried.

According to the documentation at http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=CFrame CFrame has a y property. I guess you could just alter this property of the CFrame object.

Comment: when I try it says " Can not change Y property of this part"

Answer (score 1):

```
local torso = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Torso
--> change that to get the player's torso however you want
for i = 1, 10 do --> iterate (loop) from one to ten
    torso.CFrame = torso.CFrame + Vector3.new(0,1,0) 
    --> I think that is what you're looking for
    wait(1)
end --> go back to the top of the loop, until i has reached 10
print("done")
```

Other things to keep in mind:

1) roblox characters have a "HumanoidRootPart" and animations can act weird if you set positions by using torsos. (not normally an issue)

2) gravity will keep the player down unless the part is anchored,

3) smaller waits are smoother. When you are comfortable with for loops and functions) look up "RunService" on the wiki. Using Stepped Events makes things very smooth.

```
local torso = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Torso
for i = 1, 3000 do
    torso.CFrame = torso.CFrame + Vector3.new(0,0.03,0)
    wait() --> the default wait is about 0.03 seconds
end
print("done")
```